# Https request timeout , after server restart

Tags: .net, http, timeout, restart

code looks like this

```
 var request = WebRequest.Create(new Uri(reqStr, UriKind.Absolute));
                request.Method = "POST";
                request.Timeout = 15000;

 Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();            
 WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();

 var dataStreamResp = response.GetResponseStream();
```

I call it every 10 seconds ,and it works fine. If I disable my local connection, then enable , it countinues to work. But , when server restart , i receive timout exception (server works after restart). What is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that your server is taking longer than 15 seconds to startup and start servicing requests.

You'd be getting a different exception being thrown if a request was in process and waiting for a response and the server closed the connection instead of sending a response.

I would suggest installing Fiddler2 and watching what is happening with the request.  You should be able to see if the request is starting after the server comes up and what the server does in that case (close the connection, send a response eventually, etc).

You can also then save the request with Fiddler and replay it right after the server is restarted (within a couple seconds) to confirm that an independent HTTP client sees the same results as your code, that way you will know it isn't worth debugging your client code as the issue is in your server taking too long to startup.

Harold